# Openstack 14.04 JUJU services mostly failing after upgrade

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, cloud, lxc

It had been a few months since I inititially built my openstack cloud and against my better judgement, I ran `sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get upgrade` on my nodes.  Bad idea.

Everything seemed normal upon rebooting, nagios reports no problem services, however when I started my instances, none of them were able to get an IP.  So as I began investigating in neutron, I see in JUJU tons of errors.  I am not sure where to even really begin.

When the nodes were upgrading they had asked me about a couple configuration changes, I chose (N) to any modifications.  I am guessing that is the problem?

```
landscape@juju-machine-0-lxc-1:~$ juju status --format=tabular
[Services]            
NAME                  STATUS  EXPOSED CHARM                                           
base-machine          error   false   cs:trusty/ubuntu-6                              
ceilometer            active  false   cs:trusty/ceilometer-171                        
ceilometer-agent              false   cs:trusty/ceilometer-agent-167                  
ceph-mon              active  false   cs:~openstack-charmers-next/trusty/ceph-mon-137 
ceph-osd              active  false   cs:trusty/ceph-osd-169                          
ceph-radosgw          active  false   cs:trusty/ceph-radosgw-173                      
cinder                error   false   cs:trusty/cinder-188                            
glance                active  false   cs:trusty/glance-185                            
keystone              active  false   cs:trusty/keystone-253                          
landscape-client              false   cs:trusty/landscape-client-12                   
mongodb               unknown false   cs:trusty/mongodb-35                            
mysql                 active  false   cs:trusty/percona-cluster-178                   
nagios                unknown false   cs:trusty/nagios-10                             
neutron-api           active  false   cs:trusty/neutron-api-177                       
neutron-gateway       error   false   cs:trusty/neutron-gateway-163                   
neutron-openvswitch           false   cs:trusty/neutron-openvswitch-169               
nova-cloud-controller active  false   cs:trusty/nova-cloud-controller-220             
nova-compute          error   false   cs:trusty/nova-compute-190                      
nrpe                          false   cs:trusty/nrpe-7                                
ntp                           false   cs:trusty/ntp-15                                
ntpmaster             unknown false   cs:trusty/ntpmaster-2                           
openstack-dashboard   active  false   cs:trusty/openstack-dashboard-175               
rabbitmq-server       error   false   cs:trusty/rabbitmq-server-43                    

[Units]                 
ID                      WORKLOAD-STATE AGENT-STATE VERSION MACHINE PORTS                                   PUBLIC-ADDRESS MESSAGE                       
base-machine/0          error          idle        1.25.6  0                                               node01.maas    hook failed: "leader-elected" 
  landscape-client/0    unknown        idle        1.25.6                                                  node01.maas                                  
  ntp/0                 unknown        idle        1.25.6                                                  node01.maas                                  
base-machine/1          unknown        idle        1.25.6  2                                               node02.maas                                  
  landscape-client/9    unknown        idle        1.25.6                                                  node02.maas                                  
  ntp/1                 error          idle        1.25.6                                                  node02.maas    hook failed: "leader-elected" 
base-machine/2          unknown        idle        1.25.6  1                                               node03.maas                                  
  landscape-client/10   unknown        idle        1.25.6                                                  node03.maas                                  
  ntp/2                 unknown        idle        1.25.6                                                  node03.maas                                  
ceilometer/0            active         idle        1.25.6  0/lxc/2 8777/tcp                                10.14.0.47     Unit is ready                 
  landscape-client/5    unknown        idle        1.25.6                                                  10.14.0.47                                   
  nrpe/4                unknown        idle        1.25.6                                                  10.14.0.47                                   
ceph-mon/0              active         idle        1.25.6  0/lxc/4                                         10.14.0.53     Unit is ready and clustered   
  landscape-client/2    unknown        idle        1.25.6                                                  10.14.0.53                                   
  nrpe/1                unknown        idle        1.25.6                                                  10.14.0.53                                   
ceph-mon/1              active         idle        1.25.6  2/lxc/4                                         10.14.0.60     Unit is ready and clustered   
  landscape-client/14   unknown        idle        1.25.6                                                  10.14.0.60                                   
  nrpe/10               unknown        idle        1.25.6                                                  10.14.0.60                                   
ceph-mon/2              active         idle        1.25.6  1/lxc/0                                         10.14.0.62     Unit is ready and clustered   
  landscape-client/19   unknown        idle        1.25.6                                                  10.14.0.62                                   
  nrpe/13               unknown        idle        1.25.6                                                  10.14.0.62                                   
ceph-osd/0              active         idle        1.25.6  0                                               node01.maas    Unit is ready (2 OSD)         
  landscape-client/1    unknown        idle        1.25.6                                                  node01.maas                                  
  nrpe/0                unknown        idle        1.25.6                                                  node01.maas                                  
ceph-osd/1              active         idle        1.25.6  2                                               node02.maas    Unit is ready (5 OSD)         
  landscape-client/11   unknown        idle        1.25.6                                                  node02.maas                                  
  nrpe/8                unknown        idle        1.25.6                                                  node02.maas                                  
ceph-osd/2              active         idle        1.25.6  1                                               node03.maas    Unit is ready (5 OSD)         
  landscape-client/12   unknown        idle        1.25.6                                                  node03.maas                                  
  nrpe/9                error          idle        1.25.6                                                  node03.maas    hook failed: "config-changed" 
ceph-radosgw/0          active         idle        1.25.6  2/lxc/0 80/tcp                                  10.14.0.56     Unit is ready                 
  landscape-client/16   unknown        idle        1.25.6                                                  10.14.0.56                                   
cinder/0                error          idle        1.25.6  1/lxc/2                                         10.14.0.64     hook failed: "update-status"  
  landscape-client/22   unknown        idle        1.25.6                                                  10.14.0.64                                   
  nrpe/16               unknown        idle        1.25.6                                                  10.14.0.64                                   
glance/0                active         idle        1.25.6  0/lxc/5 9292/tcp                                10.14.0.54     Unit is ready                 
  landscape-client/4    unknown        idle        1.25.6                                                  10.14.0.54                                   
  nrpe/3                unknown        idle        1.25.6                                                  10.14.0.54                                   
keystone/0              active         idle        1.25.6  2/lxc/2                                         10.14.0.58     Unit is ready                 
  landscape-client/18   unknown        idle        1.25.6                                                  10.14.0.58                                   
  nrpe/12               unknown        idle        1.25.6                                                  10.14.0.58                                   
mongodb/0               unknown        idle        1.25.6  1/lxc/3 27017/tcp,27019/tcp,27021/tcp,28017/tcp 10.14.0.65                                   
  landscape-client/20   unknown        idle        1.25.6                                                  10.14.0.65                                   
  nrpe/14               unknown        idle        1.25.6                                                  10.14.0.65                                   
mysql/0                 active         idle        1.25.6  0/lxc/1                                         10.14.0.50     Unit is ready                 
  landscape-client/7    unknown        idle        1.25.6                                                  10.14.0.50                                   
  nrpe/6                unknown        idle        1.25.6                                                  10.14.0.50                                   
nagios/0                unknown        idle        1.25.6  2/lxc/3 80/tcp                                  10.14.0.59                                   
  landscape-client/15   unknown        idle        1.25.6                                                  10.14.0.59                                   
neutron-api/0           active         idle        1.25.6  1/lxc/4 9696/tcp                                10.14.0.66     Unit is ready                 
  landscape-client/23   unknown        idle        1.25.6                                                  10.14.0.66                                   
  nrpe/17               unknown        idle        1.25.6                                                  10.14.0.66                                   
neutron-gateway/0       error          idle        1.25.6  0                                               node01.maas    hook failed: "config-changed" 
  landscape-client/6    unknown        idle        1.25.6                                                  node01.maas                                  
  nrpe/5                unknown        idle        1.25.6                                                  node01.maas                                  
nova-cloud-controller/0 active         idle        1.25.6  0/lxc/0 3333/tcp,8773/tcp,8774/tcp,9696/tcp     10.14.0.49     Unit is ready                 
  landscape-client/8    unknown        idle        1.25.6                                                  10.14.0.49                                   
  nrpe/7                unknown        idle        1.25.6                                                  10.14.0.49                                   
nova-compute/0          error          idle        1.25.6  2                                               node02.maas    hook failed: "update-status"  
  ceilometer-agent/0    active         idle        1.25.6                                                  node02.maas    Unit is ready                 
  landscape-client/17   unknown        idle        1.25.6                                                  node02.maas                                  
  neutron-openvswitch/0 active         idle        1.25.6                                                  node02.maas    Unit is ready                 
  nrpe/11               unknown        idle        1.25.6                                                  node02.maas                                  
nova-compute/1          error          idle        1.25.6  1                                               node03.maas    hook failed: "update-status"  
  ceilometer-agent/1    active         idle        1.25.6                                                  node03.maas    Unit is ready                 
  landscape-client/21   unknown        idle        1.25.6                                                  node03.maas                                  
  neutron-openvswitch/1 active         idle        1.25.6                                                  node03.maas    Unit is ready                 
  nrpe/15               unknown        idle        1.25.6                                                  node03.maas                                  
ntpmaster/0             unknown        idle        1.25.6  2/lxc/1 123/udp                                 10.14.0.57                                   
  landscape-client/13   unknown        idle        1.25.6                                                  10.14.0.57                                   
openstack-dashboard/0   active         idle        1.25.6  1/lxc/1 80/tcp,443/tcp                          10.14.0.63     Unit is ready                 
  landscape-client/24   unknown        idle        1.25.6                                                  10.14.0.63                                   
  nrpe/18               unknown        idle        1.25.6                                                  10.14.0.63                                   
rabbitmq-server/0       error          idle        1.25.6  0/lxc/3 5672/tcp                                10.14.0.52     hook failed: "update-status"  
  landscape-client/3    unknown        idle        1.25.6                                                  10.14.0.52                                   
  nrpe/2                unknown        idle        1.25.6                                                  10.14.0.52                                   

[Machines] 
ID         STATE   VERSION DNS         INS-ID                                                         SERIES HARDWARE                          
0          started 1.25.6  node01.maas /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-be8673ca-1d31-11e6-a83b-0015c5efa6ff/ trusty arch=amd64 cpu-cores=8 mem=32768M 
1          started 1.25.6  node03.maas /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-b672c22e-1d31-11e6-82b6-0015c5efa6ff/ trusty arch=amd64 cpu-cores=8 mem=32768M 
2          started 1.25.6  node02.maas /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-ba12aac0-1d31-11e6-89e9-0015c5efa6ff/ trusty arch=amd64 cpu-cores=8 mem=32768M
```

Comment: I ended up blowing away the install, I started to notice more and more things that were wrong.  It would be quicker to just redeploy at this time.

Answer (score 2):

If an OpenStack cluster is down and multiple charm units are shown in an **error** or **blocked** state, run the following steps to bring the cluster back up.

1. Ensure connectivity between the nodes and to the internet.

   - Internet connectivity is required as hooks will be re-run when the units will be resolved. Most charm hooks run commands like **apt-get update** which require internet connectivity.
   - If juju commands are stuck then restart the juju controller/bootstrap node or restart the juju-* services on that node.
   - If you are facing any "agent is lost" errors then restart the jujud-unit-charm-name-unit service inside those nodes/containers.
2. Resolve the charm units in an error state.

   - $ juju resolved --retry charm-name/unit

     This will re-run the hooks that failed initially. Resolve the charm units in the following order:

     1. mysql
     2. keystone
     3. rabbitmq-server
     4. ceph
     5. swift
     6. nova-cloud-controller
     7. cinder
     8. glance
     9. neutron-api
     10. neutron-gateway
     11. nova-compute
     12. openstack-dashboard
   - In case resolving the units does not help then look into the juju logs to see what the error is and try resolving it manually. Make sure you have all units in an active state.
3. Confirm cluster is back up

   - Log into horizon and check all services are active
   - Start all OpenStack instances and ensure volumes and networking have been provisioned correctly.